# Using Logic: Automating Employee Scheduling

Tags: excel, vba, math, automation, scheduling

This is not a coding question but a logic one, but for those who are curious, this will be build with VBA in Excel.

I have seven columns of shifts; each column is for each day of the week. So, in one column is all the shifts required for that day. There are more than one job/position in each column but I will figure that part out later. The company runs a 24-hour operation so naturally there are three types of shifts (morning, mid, and graveyard) but a total of five start times. There are also short shifts (6-hour), regular (8-hour) shifts, and 10-hour shifts.

I am hoping to create schedules from these shifts that are at most 40-hour long, and with two/three consecutive days off. Because this company is in a unionized setting, we cannot mix 6 / 8 / 10 -hour shifts but we can mix start times if they are within the same shift (morning, mid, and graveyard). E.G., the employee can start at 21:00 and 23:00 in the same week but not 11:00 and 21:00 as those are different shifts.

6 and 8 -hour shifts will get two consecutive days off, while 10-hour shifts will get three consecutive days off.

How should I approach this?

Below is a sample of the shifts (first 30 of 220 rows):

[image]

There are more shifts on Fridays and Saturdays (last two columns) than the weekdays.

The output should look similar to this:

[image]

It is okay to have left over shifts, or shifts that cannot make a full schedule.

The biggest problem I have is how to insert the days off and balance the remainder.

Comment: I use the Solver to solve weekly schedules or multi-period schedules but can't work out what you have.

Comment: What do "S" and "SR" mean? I assume shifts ending with a "-6" or a "-10" are 10-hour shifts, and shifts without that indication are 8-hour shifts?

Comment: How do you plan to get 40 hours with five 6-hour shifts?

Comment: @SolarMike What is a solver? The output is currently manual, just cut and paste from top to bottom to fill as many full schedules (30 or 40 hours) as possible. We usually have remainders for casual / part-time employees.

Comment: @Stef S and SR are two different positions.

Correct, -6 are 6-hour shifts, -10 are 10-hour shifts, and without - are 8-hour shifts.

Comment: @Beta They can have at most 40 hours but can also have 30 hours for 6-hour shifts.

Comment: Ah, careless reading on my part, sorry.

Comment: The Solver is an add-on available in Excel - fantastically powerful once you get to grips with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Solar Mike for pointing me in the right direction.

I have used the Solver add-in on Excel to derive the number of each week-start for each position and created the schedules that way. Originally, I was going to mix shifts of different positions and start times.

The Solver gives me schedules with one or two extra shifts for each position that I do not need each week, which can add up to a substantial amount.

[image]

Above, I COUNTIF my columns to know how many of the position (top-left cell) I need on each day in the target row. The Solver plays with the numbers in the count column, and the actual row is the SUMPRODUCT. Objective is minimize the number of total employees.

The difference of two on Sunday is the extra shifts created that are not needed. What I could have done and probably will do to stay within budget is to set the constraint to have the actual be less than or equal to the target so I will be short some shifts, and set the objective to have the maximum difference (lowest number of negatives).

I will then create shifts for the negative difference and schedule them for part-time or casual employees.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.